# Sort out Apple hosts

Tags: network, messages, login-items, wireshark

I have a question about Apple network traffic. In my network program I can see these three domains (GET)

http://init-01md.apple.com/bag

http://init.ess.apple.com/WebObjects/VCInit.woa/wa/getBag?ix=1

https://service1.ess.apple.com/...

These appear when I receive or send text messages from/to my iPhone. The question is:

Do these three domains show up even if it's NOT related to text messages?